# How to implement OnNavigatedTo/From in MVVM?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm-light

I would like my `ModelView` to know when navigated page has been activated/deactivated so I found the [following](https://marcominerva.wordpress.com/2013/05/07/calling-viewmodel-methods-in-response-to-page-navigation-events-using-mvvm-light-in-winrt/) article, which has nice way to handle above. The bad thing is this article is targeted to WinRT and my application is neither WinRT nor Silverlight. So I have to use whatever `System.Windows.Controls.Page` provides. How can I implement such mechanism?

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for tracking the navigation events? I think you need to implement the **INavigationAware** interface either in your View or your ViewModel (Prism will check first the view, and if it doesn't implement INavigationAware it will also check the ViewModel).

Please see a short example of its implementation, below. But the thing is you need to implement all the 2 methods namely **OnNavigatedFrom and OnNavigatedTo**

```
public class MyViewModel : INavigationAware 
{
   bool INavigationAware.IsNavigationTarget(NavigationContext navigationContext)
  {
     return false;
  }

  void INavigationAware.OnNavigatedFrom(NavigationContext navigationContext)
  {
  }

  void INavigationAware.OnNavigatedTo(NavigationContext navigationContext)
  {
  }
}
```

Comment: I am not using Prism, but mvvm light toolkit. I'm not sure I understand how `INavigationAware` will help me to intercept navigation events of `Page` control.

Comment: Sorry, but I didn't get you. Did you mean that you did not understand the working of **INavigationAware** interface? I thought you were using the prism framework.

Comment: no, I'm not using Prism framework. I'm using MVVM Light Toolkit.